# Draw 2 adjacent rectangles using ASCII characters

Tags: c#, drawing, ascii

My objective is to draw 2 rectangles adjacent to each other. I wrote the code for drawing a rectangle but I could not draw 2 adjacent rectangles. I see where to problem is but I am not sure how to fix it. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
class DrawRectangles
{           
    static void Main(){
        Console.WriteLine(DrawRectangle(8,8)+DrawRectangle(4,3));
    }
    static string DrawRectangle(int width,int length){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string first = "+" + " -".StringMultiplier(width-1)+ " + ";
        sb.AppendLine(first);
        for(int i=0; i<length-1;i++)
            sb.AppendLine("|"+" ".StringMultiplier(2*width-1)+"|");
        sb.Append(first);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}   

internal static class StringExtensions
{       
    public static string StringMultiplier(this string value,int count){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(count);
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            sb.Append(value);
        return sb.ToString();
    }       
}
```

**Expected output**:

```
+ - - - - - - - + 
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |+ - - - +
|               ||       |
|               ||       |
|               ||       |
+ - - - - - - - ++ - - - +
```

**Current output**:

```
+ - - - - - - - + 
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
+ - - - - - - - ++ - - - + 
|       |
|       |
+ - - - +
```

Comment: You do realize you're doing a string concatenation when you do `DrawRectangle(8,8)+DrawRectangle(4,3)` ...

Comment: yes.. I knew where the problem is and how dumb it is, but I ran out of ideas. Any different perspectives to achieve the same is also appreciated.

Comment: Also, this seems like homework... and if it is, you should mark it that way...

Comment: No, it is a part of a bigger problem. It is something that I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ran out of ideas? Which ideas?

Comment: @gt Well lets go in full. I am solving a 2d bin packing problem and I want to show a visual representation of the final algorithm in a console window, without using graphics. My datastructure is in a binary tree that represents the relation between individual boxes. My objective is to traverse the tree in a way that the data extracted can be merged into the final diagram. The subproblem posted here is my attempt to solve it by building individual rectangles, but, atleast to me, that is not easy at it sounds. I ran out of ideas it this course of thought process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the `StringMultiplier` extension is unnecessary because you can use [`System.String(Char, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) to accomplish the same thing.

Here's the code you'll actually need:

```
// Assume the Tuples are <height, width>
string DrawRectangles(params Tuple<int, int>[] measurements)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var maxHeight = measurements.Max(measurement => measurement.Item1);

    for (var h = maxHeight; h > 0; h--)
    {
        foreach (var measurement in measurements)
        {
            // If you're on the top or bottom row of a rectangle...
            if (h == 0 || measurement.Item1 == h)
            {
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "+", new String('-', measurement.Item2 - 2)));
                continue;
            }

            // If you're in the middle of a rectangle...
            if (measurement.Item1 > h)
            {
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "+", new String(' ', measurement.Item2 - 2)));
                continue;
            }

            sb.Append(new String(' ', measurement.Item2));
        }

        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Usage:

```
var output = DrawRectangles(new Tuple(8, 8), new Tuple(4, 3), etc...);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but the code will not work this way unless edited. Your `break` should be `continue` and there should be a CR at the end of every height iteration.

Comment: On a different note, do you know of a syntax similar to `new String('-',measurement)`, but accepts a `string` instead of a `char` as param1. The reason I wrote `StringMultiplier()` is to solve this problem, though it sounded redundant in the subproblem that I posted in SO.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective; I achieved what I wanted using your idea. I knew I should construct the string as a whole but brain-farted going thru the whole problem(described in one of my comments on the original post).

Comment: @AntonyThomas: No, `System.String` does not expose the constructor using a string, but you could roll out your own (as you attempted to do with `StringMultiplier`). Though, why bother reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

insted of this code

```
string first = "+" + " -".StringMultiplier(width-1)+ " + ";
```

you can simply use this pattern:

```
string first = string.Format("+{0}+", new string('-', width - 2));
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer my question.